# How to toggle Input in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to toggle my select then show another input based on what I selected.

```
Owned:
<select ngModel="selectedValue">
 <option value="true">Yes</option>
 <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
<input *ngIf="selectedValue==false" type="date">
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`

Comment: Also, you can use `*ngIf="!selectedValue"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
  <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
<div *ngIf="selectedValue"> Selected value is: {{selectedValue}}</div>
<input *ngIf="selectedValue == 'false'" type="date">
```

Comment: Thanks, this line of code solved my problem "selectedValue == 'false'" --> 'false'